# Convert bytes to string from a txt file

Tags: java, string, utf-8, byte

In our school project we are supposed to make a program which uses txt files to store data. I decided to simply store them using bytes, with UTF-8 encoding.
When I write to the file I first convert my string to bytes.
Then when i try to read info from file, I cannot do so because the bytes i have stored in the txt are in string format, and it's impossible to convert from String to Bytes without encoding. 
Here are the parts of my code responisble for:

```
 try
      {
        byte[] bytes=line.getBytes("UTF-8");
        out.println(bytes);
      }
      catch(IOException q)
      {
        System.out.println("Cant encode pls");
      }
```

^Writing

Reading:

```
  try{
            byte[] readbyte=in.readLine().getBytes("UTF-8");
            String str=new String(readbyte, "UTF-8");
            System.out.println(str+" Decoded");
            model1.addElement(str); 
          }
```

Unfortunately the reading gives me only what i started with, since i simply encode the string from the txt and decode it back.

So how do i fix this?

Comment: *the reading gives me only what i started with* - and what is your expectation?

Comment: That is exactly what I expected in this case, and I ask what to do in order to have a different outcome

Comment: By "simply storing them as Bytes", are you not just complicating things for yourself ?

Comment: Well let's say that is some method of "security", I looked up Cipher and some other encodings, but they were far too complicated for me. So I guess it's at least something.